# Soft keyboard don't must open when input field in Android WebView is clicked

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I want a click on the input field in my WebView and when element is focused to >>>not open<<< the standard keyboard ( for adding a barcode from the native scanner after click button on device).

I tried this code to close keyboard:

```
public static Activity getActivity(Context context) {
if (context == null) return null;
if (context instanceof Activity) return (Activity) context;
if (context instanceof ContextWrapper) return getActivity(((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext());
return null;
}
```

**Variant 1** - Opening or closing keyboard works, but only on start of activity.

```
getActivity(getContext()).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

**Variant 2** -  After using variant 1, the keyboard opened (for testing close keyboard), after loading the WebView call event from js and keyboard was closed and open again. Also, if the input field is long pressed, the keyboard closes. But, if I cancel the press, the keyboard opens again)

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity(mContext).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (imm.isActive()){ 
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0); // hide
} else {
imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY); // show
}
```

[this screen when i open activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F1F5.png)
[this screen what i need, but on this screen i hold on input field more 2 sec. I need that effect on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyMd4.png)

Comment: Thanks for edited, but i mean not that: I want a click on the input field in my WebView and when element is focused to >>>not open<<< the standard keyboard for adding a barcode from the native scanner on device.